# OpenWeather: not getting data

Tags: jquery, html, json, api, openweathermap

I am trying to get the Last 7 days weather info, but it's not returning anything. When I enter the **url** from browser it's working and returning `xml` format code. But when I run my html with jquery code it's not executing. could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

my code is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>OpenWeatherMap API jQuery Plugin</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>

        /* for presentation only */

        body {
            font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .weather-wrapper {
            background: skyblue;
            margin: 5% 0 5% 5%;
            padding: 40px 5%;
            float: left;
            color: white;
            width: 70%;
            max-width: 400px;
        }

        strong {
            color: steelblue;
        }

        .capitalize {
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=xml&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa',function(result){
             console.log(result);

             });


        });
    </script>

</head>

<body lang="en">

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/lib/jquery.1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }


</script>

<script src="js/plugins/openWeather.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are trying to get XML data with getJSON function? That seems to be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getJSON function expects to return JSON data. So you need a function that can return XML data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=xml&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        /* handle data here */
    },
    error: function(xhr, status) {
        /* handle error here */
    }
});
```

Now this function can return xml data (`dataType: "xml"`)

You can also change the url to return JSON data:
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=json&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa`

I changed `mode=json` in the url

Comment: Is anything need to call above method like button click or something? just I have copied above code and past  inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });` and ran. but it's not executed. can you please post answer fully.

Comment: It is executing but you need to do something with the data in the succes function

Comment: Where is weather Image? I got below response.

Comment: `<time day=​"2016-06-17">
​<symbol number=​"802" name=​"scattered clouds" var=​"03d">​</symbol>​
<precipitation>​</precipitation>
​<windDirection deg=​"293" code=​"WNW" name=​"West-northwest">​</windDirection>
​<windSpeed mps=​"5.01" name=​"Gentle Breeze">​</windSpeed>​
<temperature day=​"308.94" min=​"302.56" max=​"308.94" night=​"302.56" eve=​"308.1" morn=​"308.94">​</temperature>​
<pressure unit=​"hPa" value=​"955.41">​</pressure>
​<humidity value=​"39" unit=​"%">​</humidity>​
<clouds value=​"scattered clouds" all=​"36" unit=​"%">​</clouds>
​</time>`

Comment: I dont know any more other than what you where asking. If you want to learn more about the openweather api go to it's documentation: http://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: open http://openweathermap.org/city url. weather info will show here with cloudy or some other info with images. I am asking that image. example: one image with could and another with sun and another with rain etc..

Comment: I think you need to get your own images based on the data.